# 時間とともに過去データに傾斜をかけたい

Tags: python, python3

時間の経過とともに過去データに傾斜をかけたいのですが、どう書いていいのかわかりません。

具体的には
・直近1年以内のデータは傾斜をかけない（× 1）
・1年経過したデータは3か月ごとに×0.9ずつ傾斜をかける（13~15カ月前は×0.9、16~18カ月前は×0.9×0.9=0.81のようなイメージ）

添付のように、scoreの値をdateの日付をもとに傾斜を掛けた値を新しいカラムに出力したいです。

[補足]
・元のカラムはscoreとdateのみです。scoreとdateからcoefを算出したいです
・経過時間の粒度は日単位です

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 経過時間の粒度が日単位だとすると、基準日が末日に掛かる場合(29～31)のブレはどうしますか？

Comment: すみません、日単位だとやや複雑になるのでもっとシンプルに月単位にします。2022年6月中は1日だろうが30日だろうが、2021年6〜2022年5月までの1年間の係数が1、2021年3〜5月までが係数0.9、2020年12〜2021年2月までが係数0.81になるようにしたいです。2022年7月1日になったら基準月が1ヶ月ずれるイメージです。

Answer (score 1):

ちなみに質問の内容で`coef`を計算するなら`score`(スクリーンショットでは`socre`とtypoしていますが)は不要で`date`だけで出来ます。
データが`'date_score.csv'`というファイルに入っている物として以下のようになるでしょう。

```
import pandas as pd

base_date = pd.Timestamp.today()
ref_month = base_date.year * 12 + base_date.month - 1

def CalcCoef(x):
    diff_month = ref_month - (x.year * 12 + x.month - 1)
    return 1 if diff_month < 13 else 0.9 ** int(((diff_month - 13) / 3) + 1)

df = pd.read_csv('date_score.csv')

df['coef'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(CalcCoef)

df.to_csv('coef_added.csv', index=False)
```

なお`1`は`1.0`に、`0.729`は浮動小数点数の誤差で`0.7290000000000001`になります。